# PHP - PHPMailer: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estou tentando enviar um e-mail, estou usando a biblioteca PHPMailer, e então aparece o seguinte erro:

> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:1408F10B:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Não estou conseguindo resolver este problema, alguma luz no fim do túnel?

Veja o print abaixo sobre o debug feito pelo PHPMailer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o código utilizado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nessa sugestão](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/55599549-warning-stream_socket_enable_crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-openssl-error-messages-error-14090086-ssl-routines-ssl3_get_server_certificate-certificate-verify-failed-in-c-wamp64-www-cats-lib-phpmailer-class-smtp-php-on-line-369) e veja se funciona. Porém não posso afirmar se é uma boa. Mas para fins de teste já pode ser alguma coisa.

Comment: @Sam já tentei esta solução, mas o mesmo erro continua. Vou deixar um Print na Pergunta para ver se esclarece mais a questão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido!

Basicamente, precisei atualizar a classe PHPMailer, e para isso segui este tutorial aqui:
https://alexwebdevelop.com/phpmailer-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Para quem está tendo o mesmo problema, tente com **ssl**:

```
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```